# union of two Geodesics

Tags: geometry

Let $X$ be a metric space. $a,b,c \in X$ and $\sigma_1 , \sigma_2$ geodesics from $a$ to $b$. Let $\sigma$ geodesic from $b$ to $c$. 
Want to show : 
$\sigma_1 \cup \sigma $ geodesic $\Rightarrow \sigma_2 \cup \sigma$ geodesic

I can prove it using that if $d(a,x)+d(x,b)=d(a,b)$ for all $x$ the image of $ \gamma$ then $\gamma$ is a geodesic, but I'm not sure this is true. Is it ?

Comment: Did you mean to write "$\Rightarrow \sigma_2 \cup \sigma$ geodesic"?

Comment: Also, do you mean to use the concatenation operator between paths, sometimes denoted $*$, rather than the union operator $\cup$?

Comment: Yes, $\sigma_2 \cup \sigma$. Sorry.

And by $\sigma_2 \cup \sigma$ I mean the union of the image of the geodesics

Comment: What is your definition of a geodesic? If by a geodesic you mean an isometric embedding of an interval, then just go through the definition and check that $\sigma_2 * \sigma_1$ satisfies this property.